# PWA not re-opening after install and close

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, manifest

Manifest

```
{
    "short_name": "Redacted",
    "name": "Redacted",
    "description": "Redacted",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background_color": "#282828",
    "theme_color": "#282828",
    "display": "fullscreen",
    "orientation": "landscape",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/img/logo_48.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "48x48"
        },
        {
             "src": "/img/logo_96.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "96x96"
        },
        {
            "src": "/img/logo_192.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "192x192"
        }
    ],
    "start_url": "/app"
}
```

If I check the `application` tab in Chrome, everything is OK including my service worker.
When I visit the page, the app works, then I hit install and then the app is in its new stand alone window, installed, working.

Then if I close the app, and open it with the shortcut on the desktop (Windows 10) but it does not start.

It does work if I go to `chrome://apps/` and click on the icon of my app

Why is my app not starting when I hit it from the shortcut ?
How do I debug this ?

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome_proxy.exe"  --profile-directory=Default --app-id=pamomjnabgnncinjkckncinkfchkoplk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question, it might help someone...
I had to run the shortcut as administrator.